# Not able to insert values for SQLIte in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

*I am using a simple demo program, I am creating Database, then a table and trying to add values to the table*

**What i am able to do**::
I am able to create table in sqlite

**What i am not able to do**::
I am not able to insert values values into it

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Button addUser;
    SqliteAdapter helper;
    EditText usrName,pwd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        helper=new SqliteAdapter(this);
        addUser=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        usrName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    }


    public void addUser(View view){
        Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Onclick detected");
        helper.insertData(usrName.getText().toString(), pwd.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

**SqliteAdapter.java**

```
public class SqliteAdapter{

    SqliteHelper helper;
    ContentValues cv;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public SqliteAdapter(Context context){
        helper=new SqliteHelper(context);
    }

    public void insertData(String name,String password){

        db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d("LOG-MSG", "insertDataMethod Entry");
        try {
            cv.put(SqliteHelper.NAME, name);
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Name inserted");
            cv.put(SqliteHelper.PASSWORD, password);
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "password inserted");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("LOG-MSG-EXCEPTION", e.toString());
        }
        db.insert(SqliteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    static class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        private Context context;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME="MyDatabase";
        private final static String TABLE_NAME="MyTable";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
        private final static String ID="_id";
        private final static String NAME="name";
        private final static String PASSWORD="password";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(225), "+PASSWORD+" VARCHAR(225));";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+"";

        public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context=context;
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Constructor Called");
            Message.message(context, "Constructor Called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "OnCreate Called");
            Message.message(context, "OnCreate Called");
            try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("LOG-MSG-onCreate", e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("LOG-MSG-onUpgrade", e.toString());
                Message.message(context, "onUpgrade Called");
            }
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }   
}
```

**Log**::

```
04-18 13:45:19.567: D/LOG-MSG(3371): Constructor Called
04-18 13:45:20.007: D/gralloc_goldfish(3371): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-18 13:45:20.107: W/TextLayoutCache(3371): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
04-18 13:46:22.747: D/LOG-MSG(3371): Onclick detected
04-18 13:46:22.809: D/LOG-MSG(3371): insertDataMethod Entry
04-18 13:46:22.809: D/LOG-MSG-EXCEPTION(3371): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 13:46:22.817: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(3371): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "null": syntax error, db=/data/data/com.example.sqlitedatabasedemo/databases/MyDatabase
```

---

### {After EDIT}

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Button addUser;
    SqliteAdapter helper;
    EditText usrName,pwd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        helper=new SqliteAdapter(this);
        addUser=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        usrName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
    }


    public void addUser(View view){
        Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Onclick detected");
        long recievedValue=helper.insertData(usrName.getText().toString(), pwd.getText().toString());
        if(recievedValue<0){
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "NotInserted");
        }else
        {
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Inserted");           
        }
    }
}
```

**SqliteAdapter.java**

```
public class SqliteAdapter{

    SqliteHelper helper;
    ContentValues cv;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public SqliteAdapter(Context context){
        helper=new SqliteHelper(context);
    }

    public long insertData(String name,String password){

        db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d("LOG-MSG", "insertDataMethod Entry");
        cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(SqliteHelper.NAME, name);
        Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Name="+name+"inserted");
        cv.put(SqliteHelper.PASSWORD, password);
        Log.d("LOG-MSG", "password="+password+"inserted");
        long result=db.insert(SqliteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        return result;
    }

    static class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        private Context context;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME="MyDatabase";
        private final static String TABLE_NAME="MyTable";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
        private final static String ID="_id";
        private final static String NAME="name";
        private final static String PASSWORD="password";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(225), "+PASSWORD+" VARCHAR(225));";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+"";

        public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context=context;
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Constructor Called");
            Message.message(context, "Constructor Called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "OnCreate Called");
            Message.message(context, "OnCreate Called");
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }   
}
```

**Log**::

```
04-18 14:21:59.937: D/LOG-MSG(13661): Onclick detected
04-18 14:22:00.337: D/LOG-MSG(13661): insertDataMethod Entry
04-18 14:22:00.337: D/LOG-MSG(13661): Name=usainserted
04-18 14:22:00.337: D/LOG-MSG(13661): password=obamainserted
04-18 14:22:00.377: D/LOG-MSG(13661): Inserted
```

**problem:**: When i check the DDMS ....i can see the database. when i see it in query browser there are no values inserted .... why is this happening ... ive also tried to debug possible log statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized your `ContentValues cv` object. There's an NPE you catch and then you proceed with attempting to insert with `null` `ContentValues` reference, causing the exception that terminates the app.

- Add `cv = new ContentValues()` to your insert code.
- Don't catch `Exception`. Most of the time it just hides the problems you should be fixing.
- Similarly in `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` you should not catch `SQLException` but just let it propagate to the caller.

Comment: thanks [+1] for pointing flaws in my code... please look at the edit ... even though i am still not able to see the inserted values in query browser ... any ideas

Comment: Are you sure you're examining the same database you inserted in? How exactly are you examining the database contents?

Comment: I am using http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ ....... i extract the database file from data/data/package/databases/MyDatabase .... then open the file with that software .... there i can see the column names and database ... but the values are not inserted :(

Comment: @ . laalto .....Hey i resolved ... i flushed out the old db file from DBMS and compiled again .... now i can see the values :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not making the instame of ContentValues . Try to do as below

```
 public void insertData(String name,String password){

    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d("LOG-MSG", "insertDataMethod Entry");
    try {
        cv = new ContentValues ();

        cv.put(SqliteHelper.NAME, name);
        Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Name inserted");
        cv.put(SqliteHelper.PASSWORD, password);
        Log.d("LOG-MSG", "password inserted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("LOG-MSG-EXCEPTION", e.toString());
    }
    db.insert(SqliteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi you have a problem that ContentValues  cv is not instantiated properly.

please add the line `cv = new ContentValues ();`

use the following code

```
public class SqliteAdapter{

    SqliteHelper helper;
    ContentValues cv;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public SqliteAdapter(Context context){
        helper=new SqliteHelper(context);
    }

    public void insertData(String name,String password){

        db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
cv = new ContentValues ();
        Log.d("LOG-MSG", "insertDataMethod Entry");
        try {
            cv.put(SqliteHelper.NAME, name);
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Name inserted");
            cv.put(SqliteHelper.PASSWORD, password);
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "password inserted");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("LOG-MSG-EXCEPTION", e.toString());
        }
        db.insert(SqliteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    static class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        private Context context;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME="MyDatabase";
        private final static String TABLE_NAME="MyTable";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
        private final static String ID="_id";
        private final static String NAME="name";
        private final static String PASSWORD="password";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(225), "+PASSWORD+" VARCHAR(225));";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+"";

        public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context=context;
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "Constructor Called");
            Message.message(context, "Constructor Called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d("LOG-MSG", "OnCreate Called");
            Message.message(context, "OnCreate Called");
            try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("LOG-MSG-onCreate", e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("LOG-MSG-onUpgrade", e.toString());
                Message.message(context, "onUpgrade Called");
            }
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }   
}
```